# SharePointOnlineCredentials.GetAuthenticationCookie(Uri url) returns null

Tags: c#, cookies, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, csom

I have created a C# application which connects to SharePoint online site. When calling the SharePointOnlineCredentials.GetAuthenticationCookie(siteURI) method sometimes it is able to fetch the cookie successfully, but sometimes the result returned is null. Why does this happen?

```
        string siteUrl = "https://mySite.sharepoint.com/sites/TestSite";
        var clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
        var pswd = new SecureString();
        const string mypwd = "P@ssword";
        foreach (var c in mypwd.ToCharArray())
        {
            pswd.AppendChar(c);
        }      
        SharePointOnlineCredentials spCred = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("username", pswd);            
        clientContext.Credentials = spCred;
        var cookie = spCred.GetAuthenticationCookie(new Uri(siteUrl));
        Web web = clientContext.Web;
        clientContext.Load(web);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Anyone has some idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems like the user you are using cannot access to this site. It's maybe a user right problem.

I have tested the GetAuthenticationCookie method and it return null when the user has no access rights on the site.

Answer (score 0):

If user has all right access. It could be because of deprecated security protocols. Try specifying the security protocol to TLS 1.2 version.
You may use the below code::

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 |
                                       SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | 
                                       SecurityProtocolType.Tls | 
                                       SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```